# Class behaving strangely inside Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using Sinatra V1.4.6 with Ruby v2.2.2.  My directory structure is:

```
SinatraTest
    bin
       app.rb
    lib
       fix_month.rb
    views
       test_view.rb
```

My `app.rb` file is:

```
require 'sinatra'

require './lib/fix_month'

set :port, 8080
set :views, 'views'

get '/' do
  @month = FixMonth.from_string('Jan 16')
  erb :test_view
end
```

My `test_view.erb` contains:

```
<html>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <body>
        <%= @month %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, my `fix_month.rb` contains:

```
class FixMonth < Fixnum
  def initialize(mon)
    super( mon )
  end

  def self.from_string( s )
    FixMonth.new(s.to_i)
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@@months_as_string[@mon]} #{year.to_s}"
  end
end
```

When I access the home page of the web site, the code gets as far as the class method `FixMonth.from_string` and then bombs with the following error:

```
2015-11-01 20:34:04 - NoMethodError - undefined method `new' for FixMonth:Class:
```

What do I need to be able to use my FixMonth class like any other Ruby class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to be able to use my FixMonth class like any other Ruby class?

Not inherit from a class that has no `new` method.

Sinatra is a red herring here, and completely irrelevant. `Fixnum`s are immediate values, `Fixnum` doesn't have a `new` method.

Comment: Dong! Obvious when pointed out.  Thx.  One thing I don't understand though is why Ruby complains on the #new for FixMonth which does exist rather than when it hits the illegal `Fixnum.new` inside the constructor.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no `FixMonth::new` in the code you posted, but there is a *call* to `FixMonth::new` in `FixMonth::from_string`.

Comment: It may be my lack of understanding of how Ruby works.  I assumed that the `FixMonth.new` in `FixMonth::from_string` would call `initialize()` a few lines up.  The `super( )` in the `FixMonth::initialize()` would then fail, since there is no constructor for `Fixnum`.

Comment: No, `FixMonth.new` calls `FixMonth.new`. Why would it call something else? Also, I don't understand what you mean by "since there is no constructor for `Fixnum`". Of course, there isn't, Ruby doesn't have constructors.